# mongodb matching full string with regex

Tags: php, mongodb, yii2

I am searching record with full matching string difference is only a small letter in the string.
But the string having ().

```
"name" : {
    "en" : "Monginis Chocolate Muffins 6 N (150 g Each)",
    "hi" : "",
    "te" : ""
}
```

Query

```
db.shop_items.findOne({'name.en':{$regex:'.*\Monginis Chocolate Muffins 6 N (150 g Each).*',$options:'i'}})
```

Comment: Read the links. Not only does escaping regular expressions have an existing answer here, but with a modern MongoDB you should be able to search case insensitive without even using a regex when you know the exact string which only differs in case. Examples and documentation links are there.

Comment: I am not escaping the (), I am directely searching the text but string having the () so record is not coming. Parenthesis are included in the string. It is like a where condition but because of case-senstive I am using regex

Comment: You got linked there because parenthesis `()` are **special regex characters**. You "must" escape them